# how to implement Pic18f97j60 with PoE Ethernet

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, pic, ethernet

I am a beginner when it comes to mcu and electronics design, I did some projects on Arduino and other ready made microchip boards. However this is my first time building something from scratch.

I want to design a water tank level sensor using ultrasonic sensor and then sending the data to MySql database using Ethernet. After my research I decided to use Ethernet over Wifi or Radio frequency because of interference(if there was more than one tank with each having the same sensor) and range issues(needs to be at least 10 meters and concrete walls and stuff)

After my Research for components I selected PIC18F97J60 because it has integrated MAC+PHY and I can use Microchip IP/TP protocols.

My question here is do I need something else other than RJ45 Magjack
https://www.robotshop.com/eu/en/rj45-magjack-breakout-board.html

because in the pic18f datasheet it says I need to have this circuit, so is Magjack enough, if not what more I need and how can I power it through Ethernet if possible?

Thanks for your time in Advance 
[image]

Comment: google `arduino poe schematic`

Comment: Something doesn’t make sense. If you are using WiFi why do you need a mag jack? And how do you plan to do PoE with WiFi?

Comment: I had three option to send readings to the internet which where ethernet, radio transmittion or Ethernet. I choose Ethernet

Answer (score 1):

The breakout board is enough as

> The on-board RJ45 ethernet jack has a built in transformer

For PoE, use off the shelve PoE injector and splitter such as [this](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=LINK-DWL-P200).